# How to get more than 100 records from alfresco repository using CMIS

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis, alfresco-webscripts

I wrote below Query in CMIS.

Query= select * from cmis:document

But it returns only first 100 results. Actually in Repository more than 100 results are there.

So how can i get All results using same query?

I wrote below CMIS Code--

Code=

```
  public ArrayList<JSONObject> search() {
    ItemIterable<QueryResult> results =null;    
    StringBuilder sb=null;
    sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("select * from hr:hrdoctype");
    CMISSession1 s=new CMISSession1();        
    Session session=s.getSession();

    // execute query
    results = session.query(sb.toString(), false);

    ArrayList<JSONObject> list=new ArrayList<>(); 

    for (QueryResult qr : results) {

        GregorianCalendar gc = (GregorianCalendar) qr.getPropertyValueById("cmis:creationDate");        


        try{

         int month = gc.getTime().getMonth();  
         -
         -
         -


       }
       catch(org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException e)
       {

       }


       }

        -------------      
         list.add(json);
    }

    return list;

}
```

Please Help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using?

Comment: @Florinan Muller  Why you want to see the code. I don't think so code is required. i have provided the query. And If we execute same query in Alfresco share node browser, there also we are getting first 100 results.  so please check it once. Thanks..........

Comment: How do you call the query can be essential. For example, if you are using OpenCMIS and don't provide your own OperationContext it will get batches of 100 hits.

Comment: Ok, wait. I will Modifie the question

Comment: @Florian Muller , I have modified the question. Please let me know, if i am doing anything wrong....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From an OpenCMIS point of view that looks alright.
However, for performance reasons you should change the batch size:

```
OperationContext oc = session.createOperationContext();
oc.setMaxItemsPerPage(10000); // batch size, default = 100
results = session.query(sb.toString(), false, oc);
```

Please see also this thread: https://community.alfresco.com/thread/206836-alfresco-cmis-query-returning-only-100-results

Comment: Thanks Florian,  Its Working :)